# Unable to style 'submit' button

Tags: html, css

I am creating my own website and I've came to a **strange** problem.

I am using CSS and HTML while asking this question (respectively on my web); I m using Mozilla Firefox 66, the Developer version (just has some more web tools etc.)

So, I have a index.html, and index.css, in the index.html it is linked to the index.css `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css" type="text/css">`.

Everything worked until I decided to customize my submit button:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Register!">
```

Basically, I've put this in my CSS (index.css) like I would always do:

```
#submit{
    display: block;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 60px;
}
```

The thing is. This does **not** affect the submit button in **any** way. The strange thing is, if I did:

```
    #registerName, #registerMail, #registerPass, #submit{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 60px;
};
```

it would affect the button (and of cource registerName etc.). And I think, what the hell?

So, after searching up on here (StackOwerflow of course :) ), I found people doing some methods such as putting it directly into the button (`<input type="submit" value="Register!" style="width:600px;height:60px;"`) worked, but not what I wanted, also things like `input.submit`(if I replaced id with class) which didn't work. I don't know. This seems like a strange bug or something.

So, all in all: When I simply do #submit{} in the CSS, it does not actually affect the submit id. Although if mentioning more of them (like #submit, #user, #phone{}), it does affect it. Is this a bug or something?

PS: Sorry for the long post, I am new here, and I wanted to explain fully for you to understand

Comment: From the info you provided, it is not possible to discover what's happening. What is not being applied, the whole CSS? a certain attribute? Please, be more specific a try to reproduce the issue via code snippet.

Comment: Done, edited ;)

Comment: You said `input.submit` didn't work for you, that's because you don't have a class named `submit`. Anyway i'ts better to refer to some `class` instead of `id`. Try to set `class="submit"` and then change in the CSS `#submit` to `.submit`.

Comment: Oh sorry, that was a typo or something. Yes, I tried, same result.
@SeReGa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the css style sheet you have shown us looks like below, the ";" after the first declaration block is going to cause the second selector and declaration block to fail.

```
#registerName, #registerMail, #registerPass, #submit{
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 font-size: 30px;
 width: 600px;
 height: 60px;
};

#submit{
 display: block;
 font-size: 30px;
 width: 600px;
 height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Hehe, it should be like this by the way:
`#registerName ... (WITHOUT THE SUBMIT)`
And `#submit{}` in the second css reference if it makes any difference.

If it doesn't, could you explain a bit, I don't really get your answer :)

Comment: the semicolon before `#submit` is unnecessary and not valid syntax. Please remove it.

Comment: Oh. Freaking autocomplete, lemme try.

Comment: Thanks guys, this web is really awesome :D
Such a catch hehe.

Comment: No problem, I literally had the exact same problem this morning.

Comment: Haha, see ya :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `button` instead of `input`.

```css
#submit {
    display: block;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" id="submit">Register!</button>
```

**Why does it work on the group styling?** Hard to say without having the whole CSS. My best guess is that something else is applied in between, like a border. For example, you can make the CSS work with `input` by setting any valid value to the border attribute.

```css
#submit {
    display: block;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 60px;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Register!"></input>
```

Comment: Ah, I am so, forgetful. That's how it should be, using a button. Thanks, but it didn't change anything D:

Comment: @Mr.Doge, just edited to include the workaround for the `input` version. Hope it helps.

Comment: Right, [HERE](https://uploadfiles.io/oqyqn) is my whole web directory - will add it to my OP. Well, it didn't help - no border, I think it is a problem with the referencing _thinking_
@Chris Tapay

Comment: Made a quick check, @ScottZ was right. The extra semicolon `;` after `#registerName, #registerMail, #registerPass{...};` declaration is the reason. Therefore, it is a syntax error.

Comment: Truth be told: For the `<input>` case, the border is necessary after all. Or use a `<button>`.